# Upload error in Rpubs

Tags: r, rstudio

I successfully published my rmd 2 days ago but now when I publish a new rmd which perfectly knits in html, rstudio throws following error:

```
{"continueUrl":"http://rpubs.com/publish/claim/77812/a606606fde44491db3cb90a683c7192f"}
```

I searched it but didn't find any helpful result. Please help.

## Edit:

I restarted my laptop and tried again. Now I get following:

[image]

Comment: I do not see an error message?

Comment: @BondedDust I just get a new dialog box opened with "Upload Error" in the title bar and the above msg of `continueUrl...`.